# no module named 'tensorflow' when running train.py object detection script

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu, module, object-detection

I am attempting to run train.py script in the tensorflow models/research/object_detection/legacy directory however when I do I encounter the error no module named 'tensorflow' as seen below. however I have tensorflow installed.

```
paperspace@psynjt4iq:~$ cd '/home/paperspace/Desktop/models/research' 
paperspace@psynjt4iq:~/Desktop/models/research$ protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
paperspace@psynjt4iq:~/Desktop/models/research$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:'pwd':'pwd'/slim
paperspace@psynjt4iq:~/Desktop/models/research$ cd object_detection/legacy
paperspace@psynjt4iq:~/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/legacy$ python3 train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/pipeline.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 47, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I have tensorflow 2.0.0 installed here:

```
paperspace@psynjt4iq:~$ pip3 show tensorflow
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of  pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/paperspace/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: google-pasta, protobuf, opt-einsum, keras-preprocessing, keras-applications, six, numpy, grpcio, wheel, astor, tens
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Are you running the script as `python3 train.py` or `python train.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you export python path as follows?

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

hope it helps?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having both versions of python in your system 2 & 3.

If that's case then adding

export PYTHONPATH=/your/tensorflow/path:$PYTHONPATH 
might solve this.